# how to refresh grid using observable collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I am beginner in mvvm while developing i am stuck in problem i.e i am trying to refresh my grid with observable collection,but that is not happening in  my case i am using below code please let me know where i am doing wrong

**datacontext property of window**

```
 public ProjectTabView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = new ProjectTabViewModel();
            this.DataContext = vm;
            vm.ClosingRequest += (sender, e) => this.Close();

        }
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BindFiles,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single"></DataGrid >
```

**Property in view model**

```
 public class ProjectTabViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    ObservableCollection<Project> _BindFiles;
        public ObservableCollection<Project> BindFiles
        {
            get
            {
                return _BindFiles;
            }
            set
            {
                _BindFiles = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => BindFiles);
            }
        }
}

**constructor**

     BindFiles = new ObservableCollection<Project>();

**ViewModel**

public void Bindfiletab()
        {
            List<Project> obj = ProjectTabModel.FilesBinding(GlobalProjectID);
            ObservableCollection<Project> obsrvbl = new ObservableCollection<Project>(obj);
            if (obsrvbl.Count > 0)
            {
                BindFiles.Clear();
                foreach (var item in obsrvbl)
                {
                    BindFiles.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }



public void Execute(object sender)
     {
        GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(()=>
         {
          //here i have called my above bind file tab method to refresh  my grid
          } 
     }
```

Comment: Your code looks familiar... do you have another Stack Overflow account? And what on Earth is your `Bindfiletab()` member supposed to be? A method? A property? It can't be both. It appears to me as though you simply don't have the most basic programming knowledge required to use this website.

Comment: no i am new to stackoverflow @Sheridan rest i watches posts regarding this but they are not solving my purpose.I had fetch few lines of code from stackoverflow too.Is something wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you don't appear to have the most basic level of programming knowledge and may not even understand any provided answers.

Comment: @Sheridan bindfiletab() is a method that refreshes the grid after adding new entry in grid

Comment: @Sheridan Please let me know where i am lacking in providing you the details so that you can understood my problem

Comment: If you say that `Bindfiletab()` is a method, then why does it have a `setter`? *Please let me know where i am lacking in providing you the details*... your code is invalid and I can only assume that it is like that because you do not understand the most basic development principles. Therefore, you are not able to use this website, as users *have to* be able to understand the answers and you don't even understand your own code.

Comment: @Sheridan the code is in development phase..if something is wrong thats why i have used this website so that i can remove the unwanted thing is i wrote...instead of arguing with other,you must suggest the problem areas and help the users.Its really crazyyy,really a bad experince for a beginner who is using this website

Comment: @Sheridan one thing more the setter is copied twice in the code i.e the part of property and it has been removed now

Comment: Ok, I have retracted my Close Vote.

Comment: @Sheridan ok do you have any idea or solution regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to occur here:

```
public void Bindfiletab()
{
    List<Project> obj = ProjectTabModel.FilesBinding(GlobalProjectID);
    ObservableCollection<Project> obsrvbl = new ObservableCollection<Project>(obj);
    if (obsrvbl.Count > 0)
    {
        BindFiles.Clear();
        foreach (var item in obsrvbl)
        {
            BindFiles.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I can only assume that this populates the `obj` collection:

```
List<Project> obj = ProjectTabModel.FilesBinding(GlobalProjectID);
```

And this then populates the `obsrvbl` collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Project> obsrvbl = new ObservableCollection<Project>(obj);
```

Lots of this code is unnecessary... try this instead:

```
public void Bindfiletab()
{
    List<Project> obj = ProjectTabModel.FilesBinding(GlobalProjectID);
    BindFiles = new ObservableCollection<Project>(obj);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying i have tried by your way too but it shows count in Bindfiles with new added entry but it still not refreshing the grid

Comment: Please show your `RaisePropertyChanged` handler then (in an edit to your question).

Comment: ad i am using mvvm light framework so i have inherit the "ViewModelBase" which consist of "RaisePropertyChanged" i havn't added my custom handler

Comment: i have edited my question how i am using "raisepropertychanged" @Sheridan

Comment: Please show how you have set the `DataContext` property of your `Window` (in your question).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see any obvious reason for your code not working... you *may* need to look at the MVVM Light Documentation to help you further.

Comment: thanks for your support and time,yes i am also confused why it is not working.ok lets see what i can do further